# What are the possibilities of error for not Export and Import

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export, timeout, memory-leak

I have a problem of export and import in my site,

error are :

system - import/export - export  :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5y2X.png

system - import/export - dataflow profiles - export all products  :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ4Ou.png

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it's your case, but the "No valid data sent" Error, I have seen it when there is a problem in the **catalog_category_entity** table, specifically if for any reason, any category has in **parent_id** the id of a category that no longer exists.

I think the error comes directly from the method **exportAction()** from **Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController** class:

```
public function exportAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            /** @var $model Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export */
            $model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());

            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                $model->getContentType()
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
    }
    return $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

So, check the **var/log/exception.log**, maybe you can see more information about the error.

Comment: this is my var/log/exception.log,

Comment: Chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42903/what-are-the-possibilities-of-error-for-not-export-and-import